# adding specific rows to new datatable

Tags: .net, vb.net

want to select only, Monday 10 and Tuesday 50.

```
 Monday    Tuesday    Wed
 10           40       9
 20           50       6
 30           70       4
```

the code i have so far:

```
    For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows

        table2.Rows.Add(row(0), row(1))

    Next
```

this adds all of monday and all of tuesday, but i only want 1 data from monday and 1 data from tuesday. ?

at first i thought i needed to have column, by adding new row?

```
           For Each row As DataColumn In table.Columns
           table2.Rows.InsertAt(newRowb, 0)
           table2.Rows.Add(row*(0), row(1))

 ***getting mixed up with rows and columns, as am having errors on *

           Next
```

but had error with new row, but is there any way to add specific data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Linq-to-DataSet`:

```
Dim filteredRows = From row In table
                   Where  row.Field(Of Int32)("Monday") = 10 _
                   OrElse row.Field(Of Int32)("Tuesday") = 50
table2 = filteredRows.CopyToDataTable()
```

---

> is there anyway doing this using loops, as this manually. using some
>   sort of loop?

of course:

```
Dim table2 = table.Clone()
For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
    Dim monCount = row.Field(Of Int32)("Monday")
    Dim tueCount = row.Field(Of Int32)("Tuesday")
    If monCount = 10 OrElse tueCount = 50 Then
        Dim newRow = table2.Rows.Add()
        newRow.ItemArray = row.ItemArray
    End If
Next
```

Comment: is there anyway doing this using loops, as this is done manually. because what if the data changes then i need to hard code...?

Comment: @mali: Edited my answer. But you could also replace the values with variables in the linq query.

Comment: question from this question   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17789312/adding-data-to-a-new-column