# adding data to a new column

Tags: .net, vb.net, datatable

i have a table like this:

```
 Monday   Tuesday   Wednesday   Thursday
   15        4
```

this was done by using the code below:

```
        Dim field3 = row.Field(Of Int32)("data")
        Dim field1 = row.Field(Of String)("data1")

        If field3 = 15 Then

            If field1 = "Zone 4" Then
            End If
            table2.Rows.Add(field3, field1)

        End If

    Next
```

now if i want to add some data in wed and thurs using the same method, it wont let me, it will just add it under Monday and Tuesday, how would i able to add data to wed and thurs, when i debug, there are 4 columns; mon - thurs. but how do i set data to wed and thurs.

my columns:

```
    Dim table2 As New DataTable

    ' columns in the DataTable.
    table2.Columns.Add("Monday", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
    table2.Columns.Add("Tuesday", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
    table2.Columns.Add("Wednesday", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
    table2.Columns.Add("Thursday", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options.

`table2.Rows.Add(field3, field1)` sets the first two columns in your row with field3 and field1 as data.

You can expand this method `table2.Rows.Add(field3, field1, "Value for column 3", "column4")` as needed.

OR

You can create a new row, and then set the values column by column as needed.

```
table2.Rows(0).Item("Thursday") = 12345
table2.Rows(0).Item("Wednesday") = "We get down on wednesday"
```

Comment: the 2nd one am having error, property access must assign to the property or use its value...

Comment: try `table2.rows(0).item("Thursday") = 12345`

Answer (score 0):

You can go about using an SQL statement also, that may make things a little easier on yourself. There are many sites to learn the differnet SQL statements [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp) is great.